# ConvergenceWarning: Number of distinct clusters found smaller than n_clusters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, color-detection

I got this error while using clustering for colour identification, specifically when running the code on an image with one colour like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIbpE.jpg) but when I use images with multiple colours it runs perfectly.

Comment: Where is the question? And this is a warning, not an error

Comment: The message means the number of clusters found instead of the goal `n_cluster` was less. Like you said, if there's only one color, it is very likely that the algorithm will find only 1 cluster instead of multiple colors.